# Не работает :focus для поля input

Tags: html, css

Не работает :focus для поля input

```css
.popup-subscribe__box {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 32px;
}

.popup-subscribe__label {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #171717;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.popup-subscribe__input {
  max-width: 460px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F1F4F8;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 24px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #070033;
}

.popup-subscribe__input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 130%;
  color: #8F8F8F;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:hover {
  border: 1px solid #838099;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #800080;
}
.popup-subscribe__input:valid {
  border: 1px solid #1749B3;
}

.popup-subscribe__input:valid.popup-subscribe__box-name::after {
  content: url("../image/check.svg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-subscribe__box popup-subscribe__box-name">
  <label class="popup-subscribe__label" for="popup-subscribe__name">Enter your name</label>
  <input class="popup-subscribe__input" id="popup-subscribe__name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Anastasiia" required>
 </div>
```

Comment: у меня :focus работает. Бордер в #000 перекрашивается

Comment: добавьте outline: none; к стилям фокуса. .popup-subscribe__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #800080; outline: none; 
}

Comment: Pavel Nazarian, спасибо помогло